# WebGL comformance test suite different for different browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, webgl, standards-compliance, internet-explorer-11

Today I ran the official WebGL [conformance test](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/webgl-conformance-tests.html) on IE 11 preview and Chrome 27. For Chrome, the result was out of ~6,000 tests and IE, it was out of ~17,000 tests. Why the difference in number of tests?

Answer (score 0):

Because WebGL conformance test got updated.

And You had luck to land in the middle of this. :D

Did You tried to win lottery recently?

**Answer:
Rerun those tests.**

PS test suite is versioned, Chrome was running on 1.0.1 (most probably) while IE on 1.0.3...